# django How to add multiple images with foreignkey

Tags: django, django-forms

in our application, users must add a ad through the form

Models.py:

```
class Ad(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField('Заголовок',max_length=150,null=False,blank=False)
    content=models.TextField('Описание',max_length=500)
    price=models.PositiveIntegerField('Цена',help_text='0 = Договорная')
    date=models.DateTimeField('Дата',auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name='Обьявление'
        verbose_name_plural='Обьявлении'

class Images(models.Model):
    image=models.ImageField('Изображение',upload_to='upload_images/%Y/%m/%d/')
    ad=models.ForeignKey(Ad,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name='Фото'
        verbose_name_plural='Фото'
```

Views.py:

```
  def add_new(request):
if request.method=='POST':
    form=AddForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        valid_form=form.save()
        for image in request.FILES.getlist('images'):
            photo=Images(ad=valid_form,image=image)
            photo.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
else:
    form=AddForm()
return render(request,'add_post.html',{'form':form})
```

and as a result, ad.title is added to the database, and if I write `photo = Images (ad = valid_form.pk, image = image)`, then an error occurs. help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not write `ad.title` to the database in the images, it uses the primary key, it is only the fact that if call `.ad` on an `Images` object, that it will make a query to retrieve the related object. If you thus write in the template `{{ myimage.ad }}`, it will call `str(…)` on that, and `str(myimage.ad)` will return the `.title`, since that is how you implemented the `__str__` method.

The `.save()` method returns an object that is saved in the database, so you can reuse this tho save the images:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def add_new(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = AddForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            ad = form.save()
            for image in request.FILES.getlist('images'):
                Images.objects.create(
                    ad_id=ad.pk,
                    image=image
                )
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = AddForm()
    return render(request,'add_post.html', {'form':form})
```

But this is equivalent to the implementation in the question. You should however only redirect in case the form is *successful*, not when you make a POST request.

Comment: Then in Admin panel of Images Error:

Comment: __str__ returned non-string (type int)  ------- in this line------

<a href="{% url 'admin:password_change' %}">{% translate 'Change password' %}</a> /

Comment: @ТемирланАбдуллаев: you need to alter the `ModelAdmin` by overriding `model_save`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model

Comment: I'm sorry for stupidity. But how I can override model_save in my case?